# scale content over entire svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, polygon

I'm trying to view a polygon with dynamic coordinates (retrieved from the server) inside a svg space.

What i want to happen is that this polygon will be stretched over the entire svg, instead what i was able to achieve is either viewing a very small polygon or not viewing it at all.

Here is my best attempt so far:

```html
<svg width="100%" viewBox="4980 4980 5020 5020">
  <polygon points="5020,5000 5010,5017.320508075689 4990,5017.320508075689 4980,5000 4990,4982.679491924311 5010,4982.679491924311"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two parameters of viewBox are width and height.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="4980 4980 40 40">
  <polygon points="5020,5000 5010,5017.320508075689 4990,5017.320508075689 4980,5000 4990,4982.679491924311 5010,4982.679491924311"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! for some reason i thought it was min-x, min-y, max-x, max-y

Comment: Btw, can this be done without changing the viewbox? Because I'm doing some ugly calculations to get these values...

Comment: The viewBox is how you define the rendered area, so that's the natural way to do it. You could stick transforms on the elements to achieve something similar.